# Auto Update without "standard-app-packages"

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I have Auto Updates without the "standard-app-packages" package? I have tried adding the "autoupdate" package without success.

The [standard-app-packages](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/standard-app-packages/package.js) package seems to do some magic which I'm not sure how to do without including it i.e.

```
  // These are useful too!  But you don't have to see their exports
  // unless you want to.
  api.use([
    // We can reload the client without messing up methods in flight.
    'reload',
    // And update automatically when new client code is available!
    'autoupdate'
  ], ['client', 'server']);
```

Answer (score 0):

standard-app-packages is actually all of the following packages:

You can remove it but you have to add back the pieces of it you want:

List of packages in `standard-app-packages`

- meteor
- webapp
- logging
- deps
- session
- livedata
- mongo-livedata
- ui
- spacebars
- templating
- check
- underscore
- jque
- rand
- ejson
- reload
- autoupdate

So you can remove it and add back reload and autoupdate, but then you may need the `meteor` package too! It depends more on what you want exactly.